# Filling up a dropdown using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fill up a drop-down menu with the data in a variable. This is what I have so far, and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#dropdownMenu1').click(function() {
        var director_names = {"director_name": ["Aaron Schneider", "Aaron Seltzer", "Abel Ferrara", "Adam Goldberg", "Adam Marcus", "Adam McKay", "Adam Rapp", "Adam Rifkin", "Adam Shankman", "Adrian Lyne", "Adrienne Shelly", "Agnieszka Holland", "Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo", "Akiva Goldsman", "Akiva Schaffer", "Alan Cohn", "Alan J. Pakula", "Alan Metter", "Alan Parker", "Alan Poul", "Alan Rudolph", "Alan Shapiro", "Alan Taylor"]};

        var myDDL = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu1");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < director_names.director_name.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = director_names.director_name[i].name;

                    option.value = director_names.director_name[i].address;
                    try {
                        myDDL.options.add(option);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your json does not contain `name` and `address`..  It is a string array, so you can only use `director_names.director_name[i]` for both `value` and `text` of the `option`.

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript; I'm assuming it's because you have cut out some stuff before the closing `script` tag... The line `var director_names : {"..."};` is not doing what you think it is, you need to use a `=` to assign the a value to the variable. Using a `:` like that, it is being interpreted as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). There is [no JSON in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation), only an object literal, which you think is JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have at least one syntax error. Try with:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        var director_names = {"director_name": ["Aaron Schneider", "Aaron Seltzer", "Abel Ferrara", "Adam Goldberg", "Adam Marcus", "Adam McKay", "Adam Rapp", "Adam Rifkin", "Adam Shankman", "Adrian Lyne", "Adrienne Shelly", "Agnieszka Holland", "Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo", "Akiva Goldsman", "Akiva Schaffer", "Alan Cohn", "Alan J. Pakula", "Alan Metter", "Alan Parker", "Alan Poul", "Alan Rudolph", "Alan Shapiro", "Alan Taylor"]}

        var myDDL = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu1");

        for (i = 0; i < director_names.director_name.length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = director_names.director_name[i];

          option.value = director_names.director_name[i];
          try {
            myDDL.options.add(option);
          }
          catch (e) {
            alert(e);
          }
        }
      });
</script>
```

And, as G. Petriolly said, you only have the names in that JSON, you don't have the addresses. I've created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuscncqu/) with the above code to show that the select box gets populated with the names.